# Get WebCam status using C#

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I use DirectShowLib .Net to capture images from WebCam. How get state of my WebCam in C#? I mean if it's alredy using by another app?

Answer (score 0):

Build a capture graph, such as `Camera` -> `Null Renderer` and put it into paused state. If you succeeded, the camera is (was) idle becuase otherwise this third party app would lock it exclusively.

You could possibly use `IAMResourceControl` too, but it's unlikely to be available for a camera device.

Comment: As you mentioned `DirectShow.NET` library, you should either be familiar with graphs, or check the library samples - they are all about graphs.