# How in DirectShow to know if the webcam is used?

Tags: video, directshow, webcam, video-capture

I'm new and I can not understand how to do it.
How to do this analysis IMoniker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell but to build a graph with the camera and attempt to put it into paused/running state. This does not need to involve real video presentation, the graph can be as simple as `Camera -> Null Renderer`.

See also: [Get WebCam status using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655951/get-webcam-status-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Please tell us a little more detail

Comment: You build the filter graph and start capture. If the camera is in use, you will receive an error. As soon as you are there, you will realize that you don't need a "full graph" just to find out if the camera is in use, a simpler topology will do just fine. But you still need to build it and run in order to probe camera status. If this is not clear enough, just follow SDK instructions on how to preview video from camera, and see what error you are getting when the camera is in use.